# Converting C# private string to VB.Net function

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq

I have this private string in C# created with LINQ that returns a value found in an XML file.  I need to convert this to a VB.Net function.  I tried it with `C# converter`, but it doesn't work.

Can You help me please?

This is the code.

```
private string ImportoXML(string PercorsoXML, string ID)
{
  XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(PercorsoXML, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
  string ns = xdoc.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;
  var elements = xdoc.Elements(XName.Get("PmtInf", ns))
                     .Elements(XName.Get("DrctDbtTxInf", ns));
  var ElencoValori = from lv2 in elements
                           select new
                           {
                               PmtId = lv2.Element(XName.Get("DrctDbtTx", ns))
                                          .Element(XName.Get("MndtRltdInf", ns))
                                          .Element(XName.Get("MndtId", ns)).Value, InstdAmt 
                                          = lv2.Element(XName.Get("InstdAmt", ns)).Value;
                           };
  return ElencoValori.Where(c => c.PmtId.EndsWith(ID)).FirstOrDefault().InstdAmt.ToString();
}
```

Here is the VB code that I get from the automatic code converter:

```
Private Function ImportoXML(ByVal PercorsoXML As String, ByVal ID As String) As String
    Dim xdoc As XElement = XElement.Load(PercorsoXML, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)
    Dim ns As String = xdoc.Name.[Namespace].NamespaceName
    Dim elements = xdoc.Elements(XName.[Get]("PmtInf", ns)).Elements(XName.[Get]("DrctDbtTxInf", ns))
    Dim ElencoValori = From lv2 In elements
        SELECT NEW    
        {
        PmtId = lv2.Element(XName.[Get]("DrctDbtTx", ns)).Element(XName.[Get]("MndtRltdInf", ns)).Element(XName.[Get]("MndtId", ns)).Value, 
        InstdAmt = lv2.Element(XName.[Get]("InstdAmt", ns)).Value 
        }
        End Select
    Return ElencoValori.Where(Function(c) c.PmtId.EndsWith(ID)).FirstOrDefault().InstdAmt.ToString()
End Function
```

The errors are in the `SELECT NEW`:

> Statements and labels are not valid between select case and first case

Comment: Can you show what the resulting VB code was and explain which part of it doesn't work and what the error message is?

Comment: @RoccoTateo, there is a difference between a private method that returns a string vs a private string variable.. you need to edit the question perhaps and ask `How do I convert this C# Method into a VB fuction`

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing what you have converted it to, it is hard to see where the errors are.

Here is what I have converted manually for you:

```
Private Function ImportXML(PercorsoXML As String, ID As String) As String

    Dim xdoc As XElement = XElement.Load(PercorsoXML, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)

    Dim ns As String = xdoc.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName

    Dim elements = xdoc.Elements(XName.Get("PmtInf", ns)).Elements(XName.Get("DrctDbtTxInf"))

    Dim ElencoValori = From lv2 In elements
                       Select PmtId = lv2.Element(XName.Get("DrctDbtTx", ns)) _
                           .Element(XName.Get("MndtRltdInf", ns)) _
                           .Element(XName.Get("MndtId", ns)).Value, InstdAmt _
                           = lv2.Element(XName.Get("InstdAmt", ns)).Value

    Return ElencoValori.Where(Function(c) c.PmtId.EndsWith(ID)).FirstOrDefault().InstdAmt.ToString()

End Function
```

This compiles fine for me so give it a try.

Comment: thank you but in the statements  Select PmtId = lv2.Element(XName.Get("DrctDbtTx", ns)) _
                           .Element(XName.Get("MndtRltdInf", ns)) _
                           .Element(XName.Get("MndtId", ns)).Value, InstdAmt _
                           = lv2.Element(XName.Get("InstdAmt", ns)).Value             say me that expectd 'end select'. If I put 'end select' I've the same error 'end of statements expected.

Comment: @RoccoTateo it sounds like your compiler is thinking you are trying to do  select case statement. If you are trying to use LINQ queries on your code i suggest taking a look at this to see how it is formatted: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Once again, I'm only posting the VB equivalent here because the online converters don't begin to handle this type of code, so in light of that this is a reasonable question:

```
Option Infer On

Private Function ImportoXML(ByVal PercorsoXML As String, ByVal ID As String) As String
    Dim xdoc As XElement = XElement.Load(PercorsoXML, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)
    Dim ns As String = xdoc.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName
    Dim elements = xdoc.Elements(XName.Get("PmtInf", ns)).Elements(XName.Get("DrctDbtTxInf", ns))
    Dim ElencoValori = From lv2 In elements
        Select New With {
            Key .PmtId = lv2.Element(XName.Get("DrctDbtTx", ns)).Element(XName.Get("MndtRltdInf", ns)).Element(XName.Get("MndtId", ns)).Value,
            Key .InstdAmt = lv2.Element(XName.Get("InstdAmt", ns)).Value;
        }
    Return ElencoValori.Where(Function(c) c.PmtId.EndsWith(ID)).FirstOrDefault().InstdAmt.ToString()
End Function
```